# Writing on file using a different view for each mpi process

Tags: c, view, io, mpi

I'm trying to write on file different matrices, each processed by a different MPI process, mergin their content as described in the following image:

[image]

Is there any way I can obtain the desired output using a suitable MPI-View?
To help answering the question I attach a simple code where, with respect to
the previous image, the white columns also get included in the output file.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#define N 6

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  double A[N*N];
  int mpi_rank, mpi_size;

  MPI_File file;
  MPI_Status status;    

  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &mpi_rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &mpi_size);

  MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, "test.dat",  MPI_MODE_CREATE|MPI_MODE_WRONLY, MPI_INFO_NULL, &file);

  MPI_Datatype my_type;
  MPI_Type_vector(N, N, N*mpi_size, MPI_DOUBLE, &my_type);
  MPI_Type_commit(&my_type);

  MPI_Offset disp = mpi_rank*N*sizeof(double);
  MPI_File_set_view(file, disp, MPI_DOUBLE, arr_type, "native", MPI_INFO_NULL);

  MPI_Datatype row_type;
  MPI_Type_contiguous(N, MPI_DOUBLE, &row_type);
  MPI_Type_commit(&row_type);

  MPI_File_write(file, A, N, row_type, &status);

  MPI_File_close(&file);
  MPI_Finalize();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I admire your industry in re-inventing MPI_TYPE_SUBARRAY but surely you could just do that instead of creating contig-of-vectors?

You are so close.   In order to omit the ghost cells from your output, I would simply define a subaray memory type that does not describe them.

I think that could be done your way with N-1 instead of N to the vector block length... but just use subarray and make it more clear.   Long ago, vectors like this were indeed idiomatic MPI, but MPI-2 introduced subarray types in 1995 so I think you are ok using this "newfangled" feature.

You can indeed shift the file view with the offset parameter.  You could also have every file start at offset 0 and instead vary the subarray-in-file arguments.  All proceesses will have the same "global array" values.  you'd adjust the start[] and possibly the count[] for each processor.